# MySQL & PHP : Sorting text by alphabetical order for English & string length for non-English

Tags: php, mysql

I have a text field in a MySQL database table with text values mixing English & non-English entries (given that string starts with alphabets are treated as English).

I would like to sort the values and uses it in a HTML drop down box. Data example:

```
Banana
Apple
Juice
西瓜
水蜜桃
ピタヤピタヤ
ピーチ
```

I would like to sort it as:

```
Apple
Banana
Juice
西瓜
ピーチ
大水蜜桃
ピタヤピタヤ
```

English entries first, by alphabetical ascending order; then non-English entries followed, by string length. I think I have to work it out in PHP, right ?

PHP Pseudo codes

```
$result_set = ( get result set from database with MySQL query )
// perform array sort ( after identifying English & non-English
echo '<select>';
foreach($row in $result_set) {
  echo '<option value="{ some values here }">{ row text }</option>';
}
echo '</select>';
```

2 problems here:

1. How to identify English & non-English entries ( in PHP / MySQL ) ?
2. Is it possible to work it out only in MySQL ?

Comment: You may need to be quite careful about deciding what's English and what isn't. There are a surprising number of words that can appear in English text that have accents. Not to mention English text that contains quoted foreign language strings (this question, for example).

Comment: i think, in my case, I can just check the 1st letter of the string and see whether it is a non-English character. ( as I treat string starting with English characters as English strings )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following ORDER BY clause should do it:

```
ORDER BY IF(is_english(text), text, "zzzzzzzzz"), CHAR_LENGTH(text)
```

You need to figure out how to implement `is_english()`. A simple way would be to add a column to the database. Or use a regex to look for any non-English letters.

Answer (score 0):

use this query, you have to just use `COLLATE utf8_bin` and it will sort.

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1 
ORDER BY text COLLATE utf8_bin
```

working example http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/46ba8/1

Comment: Doesn't sort by length of string.

Comment: @Jack if it sorting it in alphabetical order than it will automatically order it by length.

Comment: `zz` will sort before `abcdefg`?

Comment: @Barmar see the edited fiddle it is working properly. `zz` will come after `abcdefg`.

Comment: See this modification of your fiddle, it's not working properly: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ab368/1

Comment: Confirmed not working well. I put the values in the questions into SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5fa19/1

Answer (score 0):

I think MySQL should be able to do it, but I'm not experienced in MySQL, so I can only give a full-PHP solution here:

(Following your **"given that string starts with alphabets are treated as English"**):

```php
$result_set=array(array("val"=>1,"text"=>"Banana"),array("val"=>2,"text"=>"Apple"),array("val"=>3,"text"=>"Juice"),array("val"=>4,"text"=>"西瓜"),array("val"=>5,"text"=>"大水蜜桃"),array("val"=>6,"text"=>"ピタヤピタヤ"),array("val"=>7,"text"=>"ピーチ"));

function isEng($str)
{
    $s=strtoupper(iconv_substr($str,0,1,"UTF-8"));
    if($s>="A" && $s<="Z") return true;
    else return false;
}
usort($result_set,function($a,$b){
    if(isEng($a["text"]))
    {
        if(isEng($b["text"]))
            return $a["text"]<$b["text"]?-1:($a["text"]>$b["text"]?1:0);
        else
            return -1;
    }
    else
    {
        if(isEng($b["text"]))
            return 1;
        else
            return iconv_strlen($a["text"],"UTF-8")-iconv_strlen($b["text"],"UTF-8");
    }
});

print_r($result_set);
```

Outputs:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [val] => 2
            [text] => Apple
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [val] => 1
            [text] => Banana
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [val] => 3
            [text] => Juice
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [val] => 4
            [text] => 西瓜
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [val] => 7
            [text] => ピーチ
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [val] => 5
            [text] => 大水蜜桃
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [val] => 6
            [text] => ピタヤピタヤ
        )

)
```